# Etimología de "papis"

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, sustantivos

Señoras, señores, una pregunta rápida, me van a disculpar si no hago esta vez investigación previa, pero os aseguro que está justificado.

[image: papis]

¿Por qué estas cosas que tengo en los pies y que parecen batas de cirujano pero para los zapatos se llaman *papis*?

Comment: Son "calzas". En este [foro](http://foro.comadronas.org/archive/index.php?thread-8028-9.html) discuten si esa denominación de "papis" para las calzas quirúrgicas es jerga coloquial o si es un término técnico correcto (aparece en algunos manuales y tests, pero otra gente no lo ha oído en la vida).

Comment: @Diego donde yo estoy los llaman _papis_, en el cajón donde se cogen tienen incluso la etiqueta así puesta.

Comment: @RosieM.Banks lo estoy, lo estoy. :-) Tras dos niños, hoy ha nacido la niña sobre las siete y media. Soy tripadre. :-)

Comment: ¡Grande, grande! Esta niña ha nacido con una pregunta bajo el brazo : )

Comment: A lo mejor son las babuchas para los `papis`. Y debe haber algunas cosas para los `peques` también.

Answer (score 1):

Una hipótesis: se parecen a los [**papi**llotes](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Rnc9hjx) - envoltorios de tela fina:

[image]

Puede ser que la palabra sea una derivación de esta palabra.